# Creating loop across dataframe and send email based on grouping

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames in R

DF1

```
+--------+-------+---------------+
| Region | Store | Ticket Number |
+--------+-------+---------------+
| A      |     1 |         54312 |
| A      |     2 |        641233 |
| A      |     3 |           321 |
| A      |     4 |           464 |
| A      |     5 |          5321 |
| B      |    90 |           213 |
| B      |    91 |           465 |
| B      |    92 |            68 |
| B      |    93 |         32132 |
| C      |   101 |          2125 |
| C      |   204 |          2111 |
+--------+-------+---------------+
```

DF2

```
+--------+-------------------+
| Region |       email       |
+--------+-------------------+
| A      | bill@gmail.com    |
| A      | john@gmail.com    |
| B      | doe@gmail.com     |
| C      | persona@gmail.com |
| C      | personb@gmail.com |
| C      | mary@gmail.com    |
+--------+-------------------+
```

I want to be able to group by DF1 based on region, and then cut the specific region set and send to the corresponding person through email in DF2

The code I have so far works for 1 region, but my DF1 contains over 100 regions and also some regions the emails have to go to multiple emails, is it possible to add/modify what I have to make this work?

Code I currently have:

```
test <- sqldf("select  from DF1 where Region = A")

y <- print(xtable(test), type="html", print.results=FALSE)
body <- paste0("<html>", y, "</html>")

library(RDCOMClient)
library(xtable)
## 
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
## create email 
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
## configure  email parameter 
outMail[["To"]] = paste("bill@gmail.com","john@gmail.com", sep=";", collapse=NULL)
outMail[["subject"]] = "ticket for region x"
outMail[["HTMLbody"]] = body
## send email                    
outMail$Send()

####### combining the DFs 
DF_combined <- DF1 %>% left_join(DF2, by = "Region")
```

As you see, it is very manual right now where I cut DF1 manually and then type in the emails manually as well.

DF1 data:

```
structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Store = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 101L, 204L
    ), Ticket.Number = c(54312L, 641233L, 321L, 464L, 5321L, 
    213L, 465L, 68L, 32132L, 2125L, 2111L)), .Names = c("Region", 
"Store", "Ticket.Number"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

DF2 data:

```
structure(list(Region = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), email = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 
5L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("bill@gmail.com", "doe@gmail.com", "john@gmail.com", 
"mary@gmail.com", "persona@gmail.com", "personb@gmail.com"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Region", 
"email"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This is probably relevant to find an answer: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#nycflights13-relational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I put together to help you. This will assign the levels of the region to a variable then loop over each region and get their table. At that point I just put in your code you already have and swapped the `outMail[["To"]]` with collapse of the email vector for that region. Let me know if this doesn't do it for you.

```r
levels <- levels(df2$Region)

for (lvl in levels) {
  test <- DF1[DF1$Region == lvl, ]
  y <- print(xtable(test), type="html", print.results=FALSE)
  body <- paste0("<html>", y, "</html>")
  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  ## create email 
  outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
  ## configure  email parameter 
  outMail[["To"]] = paste(as.character(DF2[DF2$Region == lvl, ]$email), collapse = "; ")
  outMail[["subject"]] = paste("ticket for region", lvl)
  outMail[["HTMLbody"]] = body
  ## send email                    
  outMail$Send()

}
```